# One-to-one map between sequence spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I can't understand one moment in the book "Inverse Spectral Theory" by J. Pöschel and E. Trubowitz.
Let $S$ is all real, strictly increasing sequences $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots)$ of the form
$$\sigma_n = n^2\pi^2 + s + \tilde{\sigma}_n, \quad n\geq 1$$
where $s\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tilde \sigma = (\tilde \sigma_1, \tilde \sigma_2, \dots) \in \ell^2$.

Then they say that the correspondence between $\sigma$ and $(s,\tilde\sigma)$ is a one-to-one map between $S$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \ell^2$.

1. Why one-to-one map?
2. Why open subset? How to understand this?

Comment: What is $l^2$? Can you also explain what is $(\tilde\sigma_1,\tilde\sigma_2,\ldots)$? Are these finite sequences? What are conditions on each $\tilde \sigma_i$?

Comment: @VasilyMitch $l^2$ is all infinite sequences ${x_n}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^2 < \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is the situation. We can define a natural map between $\psi:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\ell^{2}$ by
$$\psi(\sigma)=\psi((n^{2}\pi^{2}+s+\tilde{\sigma}_{n}))=(s,\tilde{\sigma}).$$
To show this map is bijection to some open subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\ell^{2}$ you have to show two things:

1. The image of $\psi$ is open in the product topology of $\mathbb{R}\times\ell_{2}$. (I assume you know what that means.)
2. $\psi$ is a well-defined.

We will first prove 2. Let $(s,\sigma),(t,\tau)\in\mathbb{R}\times \ell_{2}$ such that 
$$(n^{2}\pi^{2}+s+\sigma_{n})=(n^{2}\pi^{2}+t+\tau_{n})$$
As $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=0$ for all $x\in\ell_{2}$ we find
$$0=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\tau_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s-t+\sigma_{n}=s-t.$$
So $s=t$ and $\sigma=\tau$, hence $\psi$ is well defined. Note that $\psi$ is injective by construction so $\psi:S\rightarrow\psi(S)$ is a bijection.

To prove 1, let $(s,\sigma)\in\psi(S)$. Note that $\mathbb{R}\times\{\sigma\}\subset\psi(S)$. Also note for all $n$ we have
$$n^{2}\pi^{2}+\sigma_{n}<(n+1)^{2}\pi^{2}+\sigma_{n+1}\Leftrightarrow (2n+1)\pi^{2}>\sigma_{n}-\sigma_{n+1}.$$
Let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}(\pi^{2}-\sup_{n}(\sigma_{n}-\sigma_{n+1}))$, then for all $\tau\in\ell_{2}$ such that $\|\sigma-\tau\|_{2}<\varepsilon$ we have
\begin{align*}
\tau_{n}-\tau_{n+1}&\leq \sigma_{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\varepsilon-(\sigma_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\varepsilon)\\
&=\sigma_{n}-\sigma_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}(\pi^{2}-\sup_{n}(\sigma_{n}-\sigma_{n+1}))\\
&<\pi^{2}<(2n+1)\pi^{2}
\end{align*}
So $$(s,\sigma)\subset\mathbb{R}\times B_{\varepsilon}((s,\sigma))\subset\psi(S),$$ where $B_{\varepsilon}(\sigma)$ is the open ball in $\ell_{2}$ of radius $\varepsilon$ and centre $\sigma$. As $\mathbb{R}\times B_{\varepsilon}((s,\sigma))$, it follows that $\psi(S)$ is open.

Comment: How you estimated $|\tau_n - \sigma_n| \leq \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \varepsilon$? Everything else is clear, thanks!

Comment: By Cauchy Schwartz we have $$a+b=\langle(a,b)(1,1)\rangle\leq\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$ and equality is attained for $a=b=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$. Let $a=\tau_{n}-\sigma_{n}$ and let $b=\sigma_{n+1}-\tau_{n+1}$ and the inequality follows.

Comment: Yes. $a + b = (\tau_n - \tau_{n+1}) + (\sigma_n - \sigma_{n+1}) \leq \sqrt 2 \sqrt{(\tau_{n+1} - \sigma_{n+1})^2 + (\tau_{n} - \sigma_{n})^2} \leq \sqrt 2 \|\tau - \sigma \| \leq \sqrt 2 \varepsilon$